# Dispatching action in redux when click section list item makes app slow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a section list in React Native that have a large number of items around 400+ items so on each item click i am navigating to the next screen and dispatching action from redux using slices. I am passing the `ContactItem` component to the render item function of the `SectionList`

```
   const ContactItem = ({ contact }: { contact: IContact }) => (
            <ContactListItem
                key={contact.key}
                name={contact.value}
                thumbColor={contact.color}
                phone={contact.phone}
                searchWord={searchQuery}
                onPress={() => {
                    dispatch(getContact(contact));
                    navigation.navigate('Chat');
                }}
            />
);
```

and here is the reducers function getContact i am just saving the clicked contact object

```
getContact(state, action) {
            state.singleContact = action.payload;
}
```

but when clicking the item it stucks around 2 seconds and then do a slow navigation to the chat screen so anyone had faced this issue before and what could be the problem for that slow performance ?

NB: i removed the dispatch and just did the navigation only and it still slow so the problem i think is with the long list

Answer (score 0):

Probably,`dispatch(getContact(contact))` cause whole list to rerender which is expensive operation and hurt app performance.

Try to avoid `ContactListItem` unnecessary rerender when the content didn't actually change. This should be achieved either by memorization (React.memo), `useMemo`, or `shouldComponentUpdate`component life cycle method